# Parts of my fingertips are not moving

Tags: modeling, rigging, pose-mode

I don't know why this is happening. I am very very new to blender or any 3d modeling with rigs.

[image]Anyone who could help me?

[image: ng]

Comment: you need to check everything in Weight Paint mode, but maybe first follow some tutorials on this topic

Comment: I will look into this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the thumb(all 3 bones) is not parented(connected) to the palm bone,so the thumb won't move but the other finger should move looking at the rig.
give me more details on how are you trying to move the finger tip and other bones

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the tumb moves just fine. There is like a little dashed line in between the bones

Comment: The dashes are relationship lines. It indicates that one object is parented to another but not connected. You must enter Edit Mode, select the finger bone, unparent it, check the connected checkbox and parent it again to the same bone as before.

Comment: Am I the only one who thought you were having a health issue from using Blender too much? XD